# Displaying a highscore page I made in java continues to print a random string from the Highscores file

Tags: java

I am trying to finish up a game that me and my friend have written in java and I am having quite a bit of trouble with the highscore page. Whenever I attempt to draw a string to the Jframe, it just repeatedly draws a different string from the file and I cannot figure it out.

Here is the code for the highscore bit of the game.

```
        if(map == 12){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.drawImage(menu[3], 0, 0, 750, 500, null);
        highscore="";
        for(int i=0; i<=1; i++){
                try{
                    if(highscore==""){
                        Scanner q = new Scanner(new File("files/bin/res/highscore.txt"));
                        int random = new Random().nextInt(highscores.size());
                        highscore = highscores.get(random);
                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.drawString(highscore, 36, hsArray[i]);
                    }
                } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
            tick3++;
        if(hsArrayCounter >= 0 && hsArrayCounter <= 11){
            hsArrayCounter++;
        }
            if(tick3 == 1000){
                menuOptions("menu", "Ok, Back to the menu", "play", "Ok, Game loading", "Would you like to go to the menu or start playing?", 11, 0);
            }
    }
```

Comment: You're not using that `Scanner` anywhere...

Comment: You've got some code in there which should never be found within a painting method including code that tries (but fails) to read from a file. You will want to avoid having **any** code that slows down program flow within a painting method since these methods partly determine the perceived responsiveness of your GUI, and so you will want the painting methods (`paint` and `paintComponent`) to be lean, mean and ***fast***.

Comment: @syrion I removed the scanner, now realizing that it was useless.